# Multiple kotlin versions in AOSP

Tags: kotlin, android-source, android-soong

Is it possible to have multiple kotlin compiler versions in AOSP source tree and use specific one for some projects while using default one for all the others?

I tried to bump existing version with newer one but some projects fail to compile.
Adding second compiler on the other hand, causes an issue with duplicated projects/modules. Additionaly I cannot find any built-in mechanism in Soong to configure specific project to use different kotlin compiler version (or path). It looks it`s  hardcoded.